# How to execute a java program with external jar

Tags: java, jar, external

I want to run my program with guava.  If I compile my program with

EDIT: java -> javac for the compile call

```
javac -cp myPackages/guava-13.0.jar MyScanner.java
```

there is no problem.

If I try to run

```
java MyScanner -cp myPackages/guava-13.0.jar
```

I get this output on the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Optional
at MyScanner.main(MyScanner.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Optional
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
... 1 more
```

Can you tell me how I can execute the program with the external jar?

Comment: Can you show your jar file's manifest file? Does it include a class-path statement directed to the guava jar files?

Comment: Did you tried with "java MyScanner -cp guava-13.0.jar" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
java -cp myPackages/guava-13.0.jar:. MyScanner
```

Notice I'm setting two values in the classpath, '.' (current directory) and the path to guava.  Your problem is that you specified the classpath option **after** you specified your main class `MyScanner`.  Options that are specified after your main class are arguments to your program, not to java itself.

Comment: Thank you very much :-) That was exactly what I needed to run my program. Now I don't get more ClassNotFound Problems

Comment: No problem.  Typically on SO - we accept an answer that helped us solve the problem.  You can do so by clicking the check box next to the answer you felt addressed your issue best.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the below thing

```
java -classpath myJar.jar my.package.Program
```

Answer (score 1):

Because anything after your classes name

```
java MyScanner -whatever is --after
               ^         ^  ^
```

will be arguments to the main method in your class and everything before your class name

```
java --what -is -before MyScanner
     ^      ^   ^
```

will be arguments for the jvm. -cp or -classpath must be a jvm argument not an argument for your program.

It must read

```
java -cp myPackages/guava-13.0.jar MyScanner
```

Comment: If I try this I get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyScanner